# How to avoid cache invalidation in mysql innodb table if i have a frequently changing column?

Tags: mysql, database, query-cache

I have a column in my table which keeps on changing very frequently .How should i implement caching on that particular table ,should i move this column to different table ? How should i avoid caching invalidation ?

Answer (score 0):

do query_cache_type off, you can do it by either executing below statement.

```
query_cache_type=OFF;
```

for permanent entry add below line in your my.cnf or my.ini file.

```
query_cache_type=0;
```

After it mysql will not cache query data-

But if you want to cache query and some specific queries are creating issue then you can add below syntax in these queries without disabling query cache.

for example your query is -

```
select col1, col2 from mytable where col1=3;
```

then change it to as -

```
select sql_no_cache col1, col2 from mytable where col1=3;
```

Comment: How should i tackle with the problem of frequently changing enteries for a particular column ? Should i move the column to other table and cache for the rest of the table ?

Comment: if some column values are changing frequently then you can't cache that data at application end also like solr etc and if you move column in another table and any query use that column then also get same behaviour....so either do completely off query cache or use sql_no_cache where this column is using in select query...

Comment: Makes sense !! Thanks Zafar . Further ,Since this query caching is not always efficient ,Can you tell me what parameters should i look for to tune and enhance mysql performance ?

Comment: it is a vast area..first check your slowlogs and optimize queries if taking more than 2 seconds..check your mysql configuration, create required index....etc.